# When I submit the Form it will not return to the same Tab in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I have different tabs in my PHP page. I have each form in every tab. Now I want to submit the form. But when I submit the form it's going to the first Tab. I just want that it will remain on the same Tab from where it submit, but it's never. Please help me, 
the code is given below...

```
   <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#tab-container").on("click", ".tab-lbl", function(){
                var that = $(this);
                var tabid = that.data("tab");

                $(".tab").each(function(k, v){
                    $(this).hide();
                });

                $(tabid).show();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
    <div class="logo"><a href="#"><span>TAJWEED</span></a></div>
</div>

<div id="container">
   <div class="sidebar">
       <div id="nav">
       <ul id="tab-container">
        <li><a href="#" class="selected tab-lbl" data-tab="#tab-dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="tab-lbl" data-tab="#tab-menu">Menue</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="tab-lbl" data-tab="#tab-slider">Slider</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="tab-lbl" data-tab="#tab-gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="tab-lbl" data-tab="#tab-pictures">Pictures</a></li>

       </ul>

       </div>

   </div>
   <div class="content">

        <div id="tab-menu" class="tab" style="display: none;">

  <?php

$connection = new mysqli('localhost','root','','Tajweed');// Establishing Connection with Server

if(isset($_POST['submitv'])){ // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
$name = $_POST['pname'];
$email = $_POST['plink'];


//Insert Query of SQL
$sql=$connection->query("INSERT INTO main_page(pname, plink) values ('$name', '$email')");



}
?>

<form name="myForm" action="admin.php" method="POST" onsubmit=" return validateForm()" >
Page Name: <input  placeholder="page name :" name="pname" type="text"  />
Page Link: <input type="text" placeholder="Page Link :" name="plink" />
<input type="submit" value="submit"  name="submitv">
</form>






</div>
        <div id="tab-slider" class="tab" style="display: none;">


  <?php

$connection = new mysqli('localhost','root','','Tajweed');// Establishing Connection with Server

if(isset($_POST['submitv'])){ // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
$name = $_POST['pname'];
$email = $_POST['plink'];


//Insert Query of SQL
$sql=$connection->query("INSERT INTO main_page(pname, plink) values ('$name', '$email')");



}
?>

<form name="myForm" action="admin.php" method="POST" onsubmit=" return validateForm()" >
Page Name: <input  placeholder="page name :" name="pname" type="text"  />
Page Link: <input type="text" placeholder="Page Link :" name="plink" />
<input type="submit" value="submit"  name="submitv">
</form>






</div>
        <div id="tab-gallery" class="tab" style="display: none;"><h1>Gallery</h1></div>
        <div id="tab-pictures" class="tab" style="display: none;"><h1>Pictures</h1></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
</div>
```

Comment: BTW your sql is highly in danger of injections. Use PDO.

Comment: You need to use ajax for this. Try to google it. There is enough of examples on stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you mean that if the current tab is, let's say, the third, and you submit the form, it "move"s to the first tab? it opens in a new tab and "go" first? What exactly you mean?

Comment: when i submit the form in the third tab , then after submitting it's goes to the default tab as one. But i want that it will remain on the third tab from where i submit the form. i just want that the tab will remain same from where the form submit and not goes to the default tab.

Comment: @bub - Why would PDO be better than MySQLi regardning injections? I think you mean that he should use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) (which is doable with MySQLi as well).

Comment: You need to use AJAX here and submit the form without page reload. Since, it is reloading the page, your active tab is visible (1st tab).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add id to links:

```
<li><a id="tab1" href="#" class="tab-lbl" data-tab="#tab-menu">Menue</a></li>
```

add new hidden variable to forms:

```
<form name="myForm" action="admin.php" method="POST" onsubmit=" return validateForm()" >
Page Name: <input  placeholder="page name :" name="pname" type="text"  />
Page Link: <input type="text" placeholder="Page Link :" name="plink" />
<input type="hidden" name="link" value="tab1">
<input type="submit" value="submit"  name="submitv">
</form>
```

add js code:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['link'])): ?>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#<?php echo $_POST['link']?>").click();
});
<?php endif; ?>
```

---

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#tab-container").on("click", ".tab-lbl", function(){
                var that = $(this);
                var tabid = that.data("tab");

                $(".tab").each(function(k, v){
                    $(this).hide();
                });

                $(tabid).show();
            });
        });

        <?php if(isset($_POST['link'])): ?>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#<?php echo $_POST['link']?>").click();
        });
        <?php endif; ?>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<div class="logo"><a href="#"><span>TAJWEED</span></a></div>
</div>
<div id="container">
<div class="sidebar">
<div id="nav">
<ul id="tab-container">
<li><a href="#" class="selected tab-lbl" data-tab="#tab-dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="tab1" class="tab-lbl" data-tab="#tab-menu">Menue</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="tab2" class="tab-lbl" data-tab="#tab-slider">Slider</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
<div id="tab-menu" class="tab" style="display: none;">
<form name="myForm" action="admin.php" method="POST" onsubmit=" return validateForm()" >Form1:
Page Name: <input  placeholder="page name :" name="pname" type="text"  />
Page Link: <input type="text" placeholder="Page Link :" name="plink" />
<input type="hidden" name="link" value="tab1">
<input type="submit" value="submit"  name="submitv">
</form>
</div>
<div id="tab-slider" class="tab" style="display: none;">Form2:
<form name="myForm" action="admin.php" method="POST" onsubmit=" return validateForm()" >
Page Name: <input  placeholder="page name :" name="pname" type="text"  />
Page Link: <input type="text" placeholder="Page Link :" name="plink" />
<input type="hidden" name="link" value="tab2">
<input type="submit" value="submit"  name="submitv">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i use this code but it's give the same response as returned to the default tab. This code not works :-(

Comment: Thank you @Aleksander :)

Comment: But consider what @Abhishek Dhanraj Shahdeo write. In this case its better to use AJAX.  [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), or  [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)